# the sentence's meaning and the way how to access sepolia via light node

Tags: windows, synchronization, ethereum

i read this sentence in go-ethereum document.
https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/fundamentals/sync-modes

**Be aware that full nodes serving light data are relatively scarce so light nodes can struggle to find peers. Light nodes are not currently working on proof-of-stake Ethereum.**

what does it mean??
does it mean that Light nodes cannot support staking?
or Light nodes liself are'nt working?
or other means?

then, how can i access sepolia testnet with light node syncing??

then, how can i access sepolia testnet with light node syncing??